# I want to open google map info-window left-right-top-bottom side according to click on browser window using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open google map info-window left-right-top-bottom side according to click on browser window like this in picture
[This is original infowindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4hWk.png)

[This is what I want infowindow open left side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMLHC.png)

I have done this by using jQuery,,,
but my Question is whenever I open the infowindow it's open first in original position and then turn left or right side.I want to open it directly to left or right side.

This is my code...

```
// Replace the info window's content and position.
infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);                      

var domReady = true;
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function () {
    if(document.getElementById('iw_content')!=null){
        el = document.getElementById('iw_content').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    }                   
    if(domReady == true){
        if(properties.type == "top" || properties.type == "left" || properties.type == "right"){
            domReady = false;
            el.parentNode.setAttribute('id', 'infoWinId');  
            /*$("#infoWinId").removeAttr('id', 'infoWinId');*/
            $("#infoWinId").html('<div style="cursor: default; position: absolute; width: 453px; height: 288px; z-index: 101;top: '+ properties.bodyTop +'px; left: '+ properties.bodyLeft +'px;">'+
                                                '<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">'+
                                                    '<div style="width: 0px; height: 0px; border-right: 10px solid transparent; border-left: 10px solid transparent; border-top: 24px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); position: absolute; left: 217px; top: 288px;display:none;"></div>'+
                                                    '<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-radius: 2px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); width: 453px; height: 288px;"></div>'+
                                                    '<div style="border-top-width: 24px; position: absolute; left: '+ properties.arrowLeft +'px; top: '+ properties.arrowTop +'px;transform: rotate('+ properties.arrowRotate +'deg);">'+
                                                        '<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: -6px; top: -1px; width: 16px; height: 30px;">'+
                                                            '<div style="position: absolute; left: 6px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transform: skewX(22.6deg); transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; height: 24px; width: 10px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);"></div>'+
                                                        '</div>'+
                                                        '<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: -1px; left: 10px; width: 16px; height: 30px;">'+
                                                            '<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transform: skewX(-22.6deg); transform-origin: 10px 0px 0px; height: 24px; width: 10px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);"></div>'+
                                                        '</div>'+
                                                    '</div>'+
                                                    '<div style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 1px; border-radius: 2px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 451px; height: 286px;"></div>'+
                                                '</div>'+
                                                '<div style="top: 9px; position: absolute; left: 15px; width: 423px;" class="gm-style-iw">'+
                                                    '<div style="display: inline-block; overflow: auto; max-height: 447px; max-width: 400px;">'+
                                                        '<div style="overflow: auto;">'+ contentString +'</div>'+
                                                    '</div>'+
                                                    '<div style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin-top: 9px; padding: 6px; visibility: hidden; font-size: 13px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; font-family: Roboto, Arial; display: none;">'+
                                                        '<a href="" target="_blank" style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(66, 127, 237); text-decoration: none;">View on Google Maps</a>'+
                                                    '</div>'+
                                                '</div>'+
                                                '<div id="closeInfoWindowId" style="width: 13px; height: 13px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.7; right: 12px; top: 10px; z-index: 10000; cursor: pointer;">'+
                                                    '<img style="position: absolute; left: -2px; top: -336px; width: 59px; height: 492px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt6.png" draggable="false">'+
                                                '</div>'+
                                            '</div>');                                             
                    }
                }                   
                $('#closeInfoWindowId').click(function() {
                    infoWindow.close();
                }); 
            });          
            infoWindow.open(map, newPolygon);
```

Comment: Do you have ajax request? I think you should share some code. It would be good if we could see your doc ready or the line you load infowindow

Comment: Try to edit your post, and add your code in your post. (There is {} icon on header)

Comment: Ok sir now i done it. Edit my post with my code.